# SWIFT MT Message Parsing using WIFE Java library

Tags: java, swift-mt

I am using the `WIFE` Java library to parse `SWIFT` messages into `JSON` format.

For messages that are "Output from Swift", it contains repeated blocks in the `header` for `{1:..}` and `{4..}` as part of acknowledgement. While parsing the message, there is no output/error thrown. How can this be handled?

Also, if I use the library function for respective `MT` class for say field 50k for `MT103` and call a function say `getcomponent1()` or `getName&Address1()`, will it return the right value for this message with repeated `1` and `4` blocks?

Sample `MT103` pasted below:

> {1:F21XXXXXXBBAXXX9735415014}{4:{177:1410291057}{451:0}}{1:F01XXXXXNBBAXXX9735415014}{2:O1031057141029XXXXXNBBAXXX16235602381410291057U}{4:
>
> :20:2039TT20W4407225
>
> :23B:CRED
>
> :32A:141029AUD844,00
>
> :33B:AUD844,00
>
> :50K:/XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
>
> ABC LAW FIRM PTY LTD
>
> 19 MOORE STREET
>
> TURNER
>
> :52A:XXXXINBBXXX
>
> :53A:NATAAU33
>
> :57A:XXXXXNBBXXX
>
> :59:/200006547541
>
> ABC TECHNOLOGY SOLUTIONS PVT LT
>
> LEVEL 2 BLOCK 1 TRANSASIA CORPORATE
>
> PARK KAKKANAD
>
> :70:ONLY BENEFICIARY BANK IS AUTHORIZED
>
> TO CONVERT THE CURRENCY
>
> :71A:OUR
>
> :72:/REC/DAG29102014117
>
> //INCOMPLETE INSTRUCTION PURPOSE CO
>
> //DE CHARGES AUD 20 DEDUCTED
>
> -}{5:{MAC:00000000}{CHK:8A860CBABFFD}}{S:{SAC:}{COP:S}}

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you're seeing is by design.

WIFE library will try to parse as much as possible of your input, until it detects that the rest of the input is no longer part of a single valid SWIFT message.

In your case,

> {1:F21XXXXXXBBAXXX9735415014}{4:{177:1410291057}{451:0}}

is one valid SWIFT message. Everything after that is **another** valid SWIFT message, but the WIFE parser won't bother with it because it detects that there is no SWIFT block 5 after block 4 (as per the SWIFT standard), so it just treats the rest of the message as unparsed text.

Assuming `input` is your whole input string, you should have code similar to this:

```
IConversionService ics = new ConversionService();
SwiftMessage sm = ics.getMessageFromFIN(input);
```

Afterwards, you can check with

```
Integer unparsedSize = sm.getUnparsedTextsSize();
```

that you have one unparsed message and you can do whatever you want with it. In your case, you can retreive the unparsed part like this:

```
String unparsedInput = sm.getUnparsedTexts().getText(0);
SwiftMessage sm2 = ics.getMessageFromFIN(unparsedInput);
```

Now, `sm2` is the *real* SWIFT message you're after, the one that starts with

> {1:F01XXXXXNBBAXXX9735415014}{2:O103...

Do what you want with it and treat it as a separate message from the one in `sm`.

Now that you know how to parse everything correctly, you don't have to worry about the rest of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Another example for the same:

```
final String fin = "{1:F21FOOLHKH0AXXX0304009999}{4:{177:1608140809}{451:0}}{1:F01FOOLHKH0AXXX0304009999}{2:O9401609160814FOOLHKH0AXXX03040027341608141609N}{4:\n"+
            ":20:USD940NO1\n"+
            (...)
            "-}{5:{CHK:0FEC1E4AEC53}{TNG:}}{S:{COP:S}}";

        final SwiftParser parser = new SwiftParser();
        SwiftMessage sm = parser.parse(fin);
        if (StringUtils.equals(sm.getBlock1().getServiceId(), "21") && sm.getUnparsedTextsSize() > 0) {
            sm = sm.getUnparsedTexts().getTextAsMessage(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Message Type: "+ sm.getType());
        if (sm.isType(940)) {
            /*
             * Specialize the message to its specific model representation
             */
            MT940 mt = new MT940(sm);

            /*
             * Print details of a specific field
             */
            System.out.println("Reference: "+mt.getField20().getValue());
        }
```